# Definition of Chern Class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

We know that Chern class (or simply, let us focus on the first Chern class) could be defined for vector bundles over a variety $X$. I would like to ask is there a definition of Chern class for general coherent sheaves? For example, maybe using cohomological methods or resolutions? If there do exists such a notion, for vector bundles $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{M}$, suppose they are both subbundles of another vector bundle $\mathcal{H}$. Can we compute $c_1(\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{M})$ and $c_1(\mathcal{L}\cap \mathcal{M})$?

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: When $X$ is smooth and projective, you take a locally free resolution of a coherent sheaf $0\to E_\bullet\to E\to 0$, and then you define $c_1(E)=c_1(\det(E))=c_1(\bigotimes_{k=0}^n\det(E_k^{(-1)^k}))$. The power of $\pm 1$ determines whether you should consider $E_k$ or its dual.

Comment: Thanks @QuaereVerum! Then what about the second question? $\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{M}$ is in general only a coherent sheaf. Is it possible to express $c_1$ of this sheaf in terms of $c_1(\mathcal{L})$ and $c_1(\mathcal{M})$? Or could you please offer some references on this topic?

Comment: @Dick.Y Think about exact sequences, e.g. can you express $\mathcal L + \mathcal M$ as, say, a certain quotient of $\mathcal L \oplus \mathcal M$?

Comment: @TabesBridges Sure. I mean, I can always formulate the short exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{L}\cap\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{L}\oplus\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{L}+\mathcal{M}\to0$. But the point is that I have to find a resolution for $\mathcal{L}\cap\mathcal{M}$, which seems unclear for me.

Comment: @Dick.Y I guess my point is that $\mathcal L \cap \mathcal M$ is some kind of degeneracy locus, so it should be easier to describe in terms of Chern classes. Locally, if $s,t$ are sections of $\mathcal H$ which span $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal M$ respectively (I'm going to assume they're line bundles for ease), then $s\wedge t$ is a section of $\bigwedge^2 \mathcal H$ which vanishes along the support of $\mathcal L \cap \mathcal M$. One reason this might *not* work is that to globalize you need to consider a generating set of sections, so the multilinear algebra would appear to get thornier.